# How to evaluate environmental variable bash expression on host machine ahead of injection into docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file where I define a number of services. One of the services requires an environmental variable which is specific to the host computer (e.g. the IP of the device on the local WiFi network). Rather than hard-coding that, I would prefer to use a bash expression which, when evaluated, will return the correct value.

It *seems* that the correct way to pass in such environmental variables is through a [dot-env file placed in the current working directory](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/). See current code below:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  ...
  mobile:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mobile
    command: bash -c "export BASE_URL=$$(node base_url.js)
                      && npm start --lan"
    environment:
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=${HOST_DEVICE_IP}
    depends_on:
      - ngrok
    ports:
      # Expose Metro Bundler
      - 19001:19001
      # Expose Expo DevTools
      - 19002:19002
      # Expose App
      - 19000:19000
```

**.env**:

```
HOST_DEVICE_IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

However, when launching the services with docker-compose, the `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` envvar has the value `$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)`. In other words, the `.env` file is not evaluating the expression and is injecting as a string.

**TLDR**: How can I pass environmental variables into a container where the value can be a bash expression that is evaluated on the host machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `HOST_DEVICE_IP` from your `.env` file, and instead set it on the command line when running `docker-compose up`:

```
HOST_DEVICE_IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0) docker-compose up -d
```

But I wonder if you actually need this?  If you're on Mac or Windows, you can use the special hostname `host.docker.internal` to refer to the Docker host. If you're on Linux, you can just look at your default gateway address inside the container (which will correspond to the address of the bridge device on the host to which the container is connected).

Comment: I was aware of setting it in the command line but wanted to avoid that as a number of engineers are collaborating on this project, so the more than can be abstracted into infra code the easier / more likely it will be for people to run the system end-to-end.

Does `host.docker.internal` or `docker.for.mac.localhost` resolve to the device's IP on the network? Even so, I need it to resolve to an IP as the code is being loaded on a phone (Expo magic) so hitting `host.docker.internal` will not automatically resolve.

Comment: That is the only way you're going to pass in a variable set to "a bash expression evaluated on the host". You could of course provide a script that would wrap this process if you're concerned that your engineers would forget to set this themselves.

Comment: Aw man. That's a bummer and seems like a potentially common use case. Can I also force the `host.docker.internal` to resolve ahead of injection? I imagine not?

Comment: That hostname will only resolve from inside a Docker container.

Comment: So, the bottom line is that I need to resolve and inject it into the host environment ahead of running docker-compose, as there's no way to evaluate something on the host via docker?

Comment: That's correct. If you can come up with a solution that doesn't necessitate having to compute a value on the host I think you'll be in better shape.